# Does $\sqrt{2}$ contain every digit in every base?

Tags: irrational-numbers, decimal-expansion

Does $\sqrt{2}$ contain every digit in every base?

This popped into my mind
and I have no idea how to
begin attacking it.

Each digit has to occur
only once.

Of course,
$\sqrt{2}$ is probably normal
in every base,
but all I want is for
each digit to occur
at least once.

The same question for
almost all reals.

Comment: We are not going to solve this question for $1,000,000,000$ years.

Comment: So , your question is NOT , whether $\sqrt{2}$ is normal in any base, but only whether each digit occurs at least once in every base ? This might be decidable in contrast to the nomality. But still it seems to be challenging. Have you checked it for small bases ?

Comment: Nope. But I would be extremely surprised if it were false.

Comment: Well, it is true in base 2 and easy to prove...

Comment: In base 2, the only numbers that do not have this property are zero and 1 (in the form .11111111...........

Answer (score 0):

We don't know whether $\sqrt2$ is a [normal number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_number), so we also don't know the answer to your question.

In fact, only very few numbers have been shown to be normal. As example is [Chaitin's constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chaitin%27s_constant).

Comment: Normal means every digit ocxurs in rhe same proportion. I'm asking if every digit occurs, period. Rhis could be much easier.

Comment: @martycohen But we don't know the probability distribution of the digit $b$, so we also don't know if it is greater than $0$.

Comment: Probability does not come into this.